# Как мне отправить картинку в базу данных MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Мне нужно отправить картинку в базу данных, чтобы потом можно было по запросу ее оттуда получить и отобразить на странице.
У меня вопрос в реализации... Кааак? Я поизучал этот вопрос, но там и не смог ничего сделать
Можно просто закодировать в base64. (типо ты просто кодируешь и отправляешь это в виде строки я так понимаю, а получаешь и Декодируешь обратно в картинку, это так работает? Если да, то как это сделать?)

Пишу на NodeJS express, база данных MongoDB

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: Я думаю в твоем случая самое простое будет заюзать либу
node-base64-image - npm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хранишь картинку на сервере - в базе путь до неё.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, всмысле на сервере?

Comment: Как можно ханить картинку на сервере?

Comment: а где по твоему хранится изображение? на сервере.

Comment: Гугли "загрузка изборажений на сервер Node.js". Твои пикчи будут лежать где-нить в корне проекта, какая-нить папка uploads, например.

Comment: Аааааааа, тоесть при загрузке, мне сохранять картинку где-то в Корне проекта, а потом при GET запросе отображать ее через путь?

Comment: тупой вопрос, но все же

Comment: У меня будет сайт стоять на хостинге, и если я сделаю так, чтобы картинка сохранялась в какой-нибудь папке проекта, то она будет также сохраняться в менеджере файлов любого хостинга?

Comment: не в менеджере файлов, а на сервере, конкретно в той папке которую ты указал для сохранения

Comment: Ну, сохраняешь картинку себе в файлы проекта (на хостинг) - менеджер файлов

Comment: При всём уважении к ответу и комментариям, это всё таки ответ не на тот вопрос,котрый был задан. В некотрых случаях хренение картинок в базе предпочтительнее храннеия в файловой системе. С другой стороны, я уверен, что такой код гуглится без особых проблем...

Answer (score 2):

Я написал методы с base64, конвертацией в буфер и обратно, записью и чтением из MDB может чем-то тебе поможет.

UPD: url для подключения к mdb изменился.

```
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const fs = require('fs');
//const url = 'mongodb://username:password@ds123456.mlab.com:12345/terba';// deprecated
const url = 'mongodb+srv://<userName>:<pasword>@basName.7jsay.mongodb.net/<myFirstDatabaseName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

function mdbConnect(operation, data){
  mongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client){
      const db = client.db("terba");//Твоё наименование
      const collection = db.collection("user");//Твоё наименование
      if (operation === "update") {// Запрос для обновления твоей фотки в БД 
        collection.updateOne(
            {_id:"myPhoto"}, //id документа коллекции "user" в который будет вставляться картинка
            {$set:{photo:data}},//команда для вставки значения data в поле photo в документ с _id:"myPhoto"
            {upsert:true},//создаст документ с _id:"myPhoto" полем photo и значением data если такого нет в БД
            function(err, res){//функция по окончанию выполнения операции
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              }else{
                console.log(res.result.nModified, res.result.upserted)//На что тебе надо обратить внимание
              }
            }
          );
      }
      if (operation === "find") {// Запрос для поиска твоей фотки в БД по значению в поле _id
        collection.find({_id:data}).forEach( photo =>{
          console.log(photo)//Здесь твоя фотка в виде Buffer`a
          let string64 = buffer.toString('base64');//можешь конвертировать в base64 если надо 
        })
      }
      client.close();    
  });
}

function fsr(){
  let path = "C:\\express\\myProject\\img\\0.jpg" //Это путь к картинке на диске
  let data = fs.readFileSync(path).toString('base64');//читаешь картинку при помощи fs и конвертишь в base64
  let buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');//конвертируешь обратно в buffer

  // console.log(data,buf)
  mdbConnect("update", buf)//пишешь в mdb буфер, можешь base64 попробовать он в data лежит
}
mdbConnect("find", "myPhoto")//читаешь из mdb  
function fsw(data){
  fs.writeFileSync("C:\\express\\myProject\\img\\0.jpg", data, 'base64',(err)=>{//читаешь строку data в base64 и пишешь на диск кртинку .jpg
    console.log(err);
  });
}

let htmlTag = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,"'+data+'></img>'/*создаёшь строку тега img с атрибутом src 
 пишешь туда картинку в base64 отправляешь её клиенту*/

//На клиенте что-то из этого
 // document.getElementById('as').innerHTML="<img src="+image.src+">";//Вставляешь на клиенте в контейнер с id "as" например, или куда тебе надо
 // function createImg (base64) { //Или в тело документа
  //  var image = new Image();
  //  image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+base64;
  //  document.body.appendChild(image);
  //}
```